# Android 1 Parent ScrollView, 3 TextView with vertical scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a question with the android programming.

I have a parent scrollview for whole activity, and there are three textviews with scrolling function. However, when I used the following code it seems to be not working at all. Only the parent scrolling is available.

```
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register_terms_fragment, container, false);
        TextView basicTermView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_terms_basic_info);
        TextView purposeTermView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_terms_purpose_info);
        TextView provideTermView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_terms_provide_info);
        TextView previous = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_terms_pre);
        TextView next = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_terms_next);

        basicTermView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        purposeTermView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        provideTermView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

How should I change the codes?
Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a scrollable View, like `TextView` or `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, inside a `ScrollView`. So use your simple TextView inside a normal layout and add android:scrollbars property to it or you can use view's customised class which will calculate view's width/height programatically and use `ScrollView` as it's parent.

As an example, to use `Listview` inside scrollview, we need to use following customised class of `Listview` which will calculate list items height and set it.

```
public class ExpandedListView extends ListView {

private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
private int old_count = 0;

public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
    super(context, attrs);
}   

public ExpandedListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getCount() != old_count) {
        this.setScrollContainer(false);
        old_count = getCount();
        params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getCount()
                * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight() : 0);
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Comment: What is this?  **you can use view's customised class** can u elaborate please? @Beena

Comment: Yes sure. I have edited my answer. You can have a look.